# Matroids of hypercubes

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, computer-science, matroid-theory, oriented-matroids

Let $M_k$ be the (oriented) matroid of the $2^k$ points $B_k = \{-1, 1\}^k$ in $\mathbb R^k$. In other words, the (oriented) circuits of $M_k$ are the minimal (signed) linear dependences among $B_k$.

What do we know about these matroids and in particular their circuits? I'd appreciate pointers to prior work.

Answer (score 3):

A.O. Matveev's [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07024.pdf) discusses these these matroids, but with a focus on topes rather than circuits.